# Android 6: connect as camera per default

Tags: adb, usb, usb-connection-mode, 6.0-marshmallow

When I connect an Android 6 phone with my pc via USB, it always connects as "USB for charging". I have to set it to "connect as camera" (PTP) manually (for ADB to work) every time.

Can I set a default option somewhere and haven't found it yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there may be a hack around somewhere (I don't have Android M yet), Google, in the [changelog of Android 6.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-usb) has noted:

> Device connections through the USB port are now set to charge-only mode by default. To access the device and its content over a USB connection, users must explicitly grant permission for such interactions.

Well, the answer is no for now, officially, that is.