# i never get the popup about usb connection when i connect my moto g android 6.0 to pc

Tags: motorola-moto-g, 6.0-marshmallow

i never get the popup about usb connection when i connect my moto g 3rd generation android 6.0 to pc. due to it, I am not able to connect my phone to any pc or laptop. it is in the default charging mode.

Comment: What USB mode is configured in *Settings › Storage* (tap the "overflow menu" button there)? Could it be MTP is disabled on the device?

Comment: @Izzy Marshmallow does not have these options in storage like previous Android versions, there are no options to change any settings except for the SD Card in the Settings Storage menu.

Comment: @acejavelin Oh – I didn't know that (I'm not one of the 0.7% who already have Marshmallow on their devices). Thanks for the detail!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not your phone or pc. You need to change your usb cable and install a usb driver from the respective brand.

Comment: Why? If I read "is in the default charging mode", it might well be the Moto G is just not offering itself as MTP is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Marshmallow, on the Moto G 2015 at least, does not give a pop-up like Lollipop did, you must manually grab the pull-down menu and select USB Charge Only and switch it to MPT each connection.

There is an option in Developer Options to set the default USB operation, but the setting seems to have no effect on operation. As of the current MM release it isn't known if this a bug or as designed because Moto hasn't made an official comment on it.

Comment: I'd say it is [status-by-design](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/127508/96277).

Comment: @Firelord I get that, but there is clearly an option in Developer Options called "Select USB Configuration" with options of Charge Only, MPT, PTP, RNDIS, Audio Source, or MIDI. Some users assumed this was the new place to select default behavior, the was my part of my reference.

Answer (score -1):

It's a known issue. Google wants you to use their cloud and not access Android like its a USB drive. It's stupid and nothing more than vendor lockin, because if you're in the situation I'm in, I can't get my files off my phone except for slow methods.